# Não consigo fazer o envio para mais de um e-mail

Tags: php

Tenho o seguinte código para envio de e-mail, porém apenas no primeiro e-mail recebe o segundo não.

```
$to  = "gladisonperosini@gmail.com";
$to  .= "guaraparivirtual@gmail.com";

$subject = 'Guarapari Virtual - Corretores On-Line';

$message = "
Prezado cliente!<p>
<b>{$enviar_gc_nome}</b> visitou o Guarapari Virtual e enviou uma solicitação de orçamento para você pelo canal Corretores On-Line.<p>
";
$message .= '<b>E-Mail: </b>'.$enviar_gc_email.'<p>';
$message .= '<b>Telefone: </b>'.$enviar_gc_telefone.'<p>';
$message .= '<b>Data da entrada: </b>'.$enviar_gc_dataentrada.'<p>';
$message .= '<b>Data da saída: </b>'.$enviar_gc_datasaida.'<p>';
$message .= '<b>Número de adultos: </b>'.$enviar_gc_nadultos.'<p>';
$message .= '<b>Número de crianças: </b>'.$enviar_gc_ncriancas.'<p>';
$message .= '<b>Mensagem: </b>'.$enviar_gc_msg.'<p>';
$message .= '<p>';
$message .= 'Obrigado!';

$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

$headers .= "From: {$enviar_gc_nome} <{$enviar_gc_email}>" . "\r\n";

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Comment: tente separar os emails com uma vírgula (http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)

Comment: @thiagoalessio fiz, mas continuo recebendo apenas no primeiro email

Comment: separar por vírgula como @thiagoalessio mencionou funciona perfeitamente para mim. Você pode também adicionar o segundo email ao `CC` no header, assim: `$headers .= "\n Cc: guaraparivirtual@gmail.com";`

Comment: @RicardoPontual Infelizmente para mim não está funcionando

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dessa maneira deve funcionar, pois é o modo recomendado na documentação:

```
$to  = 'gladisonperosini@gmail.com' . ', ';
$to .= 'guaraparivirtual@gmail.com';
```